# Filling in .po files for translation of phrases with variable content

Tags: django, translation

I wasn't able to find in the doc, but I have no idea how to translate phrases that contain variable content.

I have the following phrase in my Django view:

```
apple_count = 100    
a = _('I have %d apples' % apple_count)
```

After running `makemessages`, I have the following auto-generated content in .po file:

```
msgid "I have %d apples"
msgstr ""
```

I have tried several combinations, like this one:

```
msgid "I have %d apples"
msgstr "У меня есть %d яблок"
```

and this one:

```
msgid "I have apples"
msgstr "У меня есть яблок"
```

And yet no success - when changing the language to Russian, I still see the phrase in English, rather than Russsian. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by no success? What *does* happen?

Comment: See the updated question. it's not translated. The phrase renders in English even when I change the language

Comment: Have you `compilemessages` too?

Comment: do you have all messages in English or only this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named-string interpolation syntax

```
apple_count = 100    
_('I have %(apple_count) apples') % {'apple_count': apple_count)
```

[Internationalization: in Python code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code)

Comment: You're brackets are mis matched, and uneven?

Comment: You forgot "d" after "apple_count" and messed up the brackets